# Get photo path using jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="file" id="photo">
```

How to get photo path using jQuery? I don't want to use a form cause i don't want to refresh the page after submitting a form.

Comment: Where are you getting the URL from?

Comment: There is no url here, the image is on the user's system, do you want to preview the image?

Comment: No it's not important for me preview, I want to get the url and save path in a variable and insert it in db using ajax but i don;t know how to get the file path.

Comment: Check out the HTML 5 FileReader api

Comment: Check this https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**http://jsfiddle.net/ddz8N/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#photo").click(function(){
    var imageUrl = $("#photo").attr('src');
    $(".label").append("<br>" + imageUrl);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by URL you mean the path chosen by the user, in that case, use a `change` event and grab the value:

```
$("#photo").change(function() {
    var url = this.value;
});
```

Comment: File control `Value` will be the `physical path` and not the url :)

Comment: @Murali -- Yup, I'm pretty sure that's whats being sought after, waiting on OP to confirm / deny.

Comment: This will not always return a disk path for security reasons. For instance, Chrome will return c:/fakepath/...

Comment: OP -- why did you pick as answer the .click answer instead of this one?